# React: Uncontrolled radio button input with value attribute throws warning

Tags: forms, reactjs

I've read through [the React docs for forms](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), and I understand that an `<input>` element with a `value` attribute will create a controlled input. However, for a radio button or checkbox, shouldn't the input only be controlled if it has a `checked` attribute, and ignore the existence of a `value` attribute?

Typically the `value` attribute of a radio button or checkbox is not representative of its state, but rather of the value that should be passed back to the server.

I'm getting an error suggesting that the docs are correct and that you can't put a `value` attribute on an uncontrolled radio button input. The [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fptbfwy4/) shows the error I'm getting in the console when I click on the radio buttons:

> Warning: Form is changing a uncontrolled input of type radio to be
>   controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to
>   controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

If I remove the value attributes from the inputs, the error no longer appears [[JSFiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/7zqe786t/).

So is there any way to include a value on an uncontrolled radio button (or checkbox) input with React?

Comment: yes use `defaultValue`

Comment: @azium Ach, of course that makes sense. Thanks!